# Should I press forward (w) when skiing?

Tags: tribes-ascend

In Tribes: Ascend, the in-game skiing tutorials cover game mechanics (ski down slopes, jetpack uphill) but not controls. It feels like I'm more maneuverable when not pressing forward all the time, but I wonder if I'm not achieving maximum velocity if I don't press forward. Should I be pressing forward (<kbd>w</kbd>) while skiing to go forward? Or should I just let momentum carry me while skiing?

Comment: Related: does 'wearing' skis in midair slow you down?  Apparently it's a troll of a question and the answer is "a tiny bit".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It really depends on what you want. If you hold forward, you'll go faster, but you won't be as maneuverable. I usually hold forward while I'm skiing, as I think speed is more important than maneuverability in Tribes: Ascend.

Comment: In my (limited) experience with the game, slowing down will just get you headshot from across the map.

Comment: So you can't reach your theoretical maximum speed unless you're holding forward along your skiing path?

Comment: @wes IIRC there isn't a "theoretical maximum speed", at least not one that you're likely to reach in a real game. There were speed caps but they removed them early in the beta. W just provides you with some extra forward acceleration, is all.

Answer (score -1):

Try to not use forward at high speed, I notice a big difference in both speed and maneuverability (strafe keys gets locked while pressing forward)!

Use forward (and backward if you must) to land properly...